# Download zip file locally to tempfile, extract files to tempfile, and list the files

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I am trying to get back into python, and I am not sure where to start, but I want to download a zip file locally to temp, extract the files, and then list the files (which are 99.99% of the time csv files).  I want to list the files so that I can further process one of the files based on logic with the benefit of the temp directory being removed automatically.

I can do most of above in R fairly succinctly, but my requirements are to map this idea to python and from my initial Google searches, the solutions that I am finding do not appear to be straightforward nor do exactly what I am looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably best to use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start by downloading the file via [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
import requests

results = requests.get('<url_to_zip>')
with open('/tmp/zip_folder.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(results.content)
```

We then extract the zip file to /tmp using [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract)

```
import zipfile
file = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/zip_folder.zip')
file.extractall(path='/tmp')
```

We then list the files.

```
files = os.listdir('/tmp/zip_folder')
for file in files:
    if 'csv' in file:
        print(file)
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  In the first block, I assume that it should be `f.write(results.content)`.  Maybe this is out of scope, but in that same block, where the external zip file is written locally, can that too be in a temp file?

Comment: Thanks again.  The last part was to look for csv files, but I was able to do that with `import glob; files = glob.glob(path + "*csv*")` where `path = "/tmp/"`.

Comment: tempfile in python is an actual thing, not an idea. What you've done here is download to a "temporary file." Google searches for unzip to tempfile, incorrectly brought me here.